# Understanding role="complementary" attribute and <aside> tag

Tags: html, links, semantic-web, menu, pop-up

In MDN the documentation for [ARIA: complementary role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Complementary_role) says:

> The complementary landmark role is used to designate a supporting section that relates to the main content, yet can stand alone when separated.

and:

> These sections are frequently presented as sidebars or call-out boxes.

and:

> If possible, use the HTML `<aside>` element instead.

### My questions

- Is `<div role="complementary">` equal to `<aside>`?
- Sidebars, call-out ("call us now") boxes **and what else**, primarily (JavaScript modals?, Chat now popups?);

Answer (score 2):

**Is `<div role="complementary">` equal to `<aside>`?**

In the docs is written the exact answer to this:

> *Note: Using the  element will automatically communicate a section has a role of complementary. Developers should always prefer
> using the correct semantic HTML element over using ARIA.*

So the answer is, yes, they are equal, but you should use the correct html tag instaed of ARIA.

**About what else they can be used?**

First thing in my mind is calendar aside section, or forecast for weather sites/apps, if its coocking site it can be recomendation aside section with recipes or something else, or any recomendation for the purposes of the app. As the name says `<aside>`, just an addition to the main content/information that is given to the user.